# C# Crop transparent parts in an image

Tags: c#, image, transparent, crop, pixel

I have this image:

[image]

and I wrote a code that supposed to crop only the part with the black dots
(the code is built for 1-color images only),
without all of the transparent pixels around the dots,
and then return the image after the crop,
but for some reason, when it gets to a black pixel,
it does not recognize that this is a black pixel,
and because of that, it skips the 'if' statement.

**Here is the code:**

```
    private Image cropTransparency(Image image)
    {
        Bitmap imageCrop = new Bitmap(image);
        imageCrop.Save(@"C:\Users\Nehoray\Desktop\Test.png");
        Point min = new Point(imageCrop.Width, imageCrop.Height);
        Point max = new Point(imageCrop.Width, imageCrop.Height);
        for (int w = 0; w < imageCrop.Width; w++)
        {
            //'w' stands for Width
            for (int h = 0; h < imageCrop.Height; h++)
            {
                //'h' stands for Height
                Color check = imageCrop.GetPixel(w, h);
                if (check == Color.Black)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Found a white pixel!");
                    if (w < min.X)
                    {
                        min.X = w;
                    }
                    if (h < min.Y)
                    {
                        min.Y = h;
                    }
                    if (w > max.X)
                    {
                        max.X = w;
                    }
                    if (h > max.Y)
                    {
                        max.Y = h;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        imageCrop = new Bitmap(max.X - min.X, max.Y - min.Y);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imageCrop);
        Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(max.X - min.X, max.Y - min.Y));
        g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, max.X - min.X, max.Y - min.Y), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.Save();
        return imageCrop;
    }
```

If you find out why it does not recognize when there is a black pixel, please let me know..
thanks anyway :)

Comment: good luck with clicking away all the message boxes ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few issues with this code:

```
    Point max = new Point(imageCrop.Width, imageCrop.Height);
```

How will a point ever be greater than the max, when the max is initialised to the maximum value? This should be `(0,0)`

```
Color check = imageCrop.GetPixel(w, h);
if (check == Color.Black)
```

I'm not sure this does what you think it will. You have a 32-bit image, with an alpha channel, so you need to take the alpha values into account. Also, you're comparing against a predefined colour which has a reference that won't match your pixel even if all 4 channels are a match. You possibly just want to check for the alpha component being non-zero. If you only compare the colour channels, be aware that transparent pixels may well have a matching colour, producing unexpected results.

```
Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(max.X - min.X, max.Y - min.Y));
```

Why are you cropping from `0,0`? Your rectangle should begin at `min.X, min.Y`

```
g.Save();
```

This doesn't save the image, you know that right? You save the image, unmodified at the start of your code, and then never re-save it once you've cropped it (I assume this stuff, including the hard-coded path, is for debug, but even then it seems you probably meant to write the image here)

Comment: Thanks you so much,
all of your tips helped me solve my problem!
Its all working ok now :)

Comment: Just adding a performance concern, I don't think GetPixel would fit in this case. You should consider working with Bitmap.LockBits (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
private Image cropTransparency(Image image)
    {
        Bitmap imageCrop = new Bitmap(image); // aca paso la imagen original a Bitmap
        //imageCrop.Save(@"tmp.png");
        Point min = new Point(imageCrop.Width, imageCrop.Height);
        Point max = new Point(0, 0);
        for (int w = 0; w < imageCrop.Width; w++)
        {
            //'w' stands for Width
            for (int h = 0; h < imageCrop.Height; h++)
            {
                //'h' stands for Height
                Color check = imageCrop.GetPixel(w, h);
                if (check == Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found a white pixel!");
                    if (w < min.X)
                    {
                        min.X = w;
                    }
                    if (h < min.Y)
                    {
                        min.Y = h;
                    }
                    if (w > max.X)
                    {
                        max.X = w;
                    }
                    if (h > max.Y)
                    {
                        max.Y = h;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        imageCrop = new Bitmap(max.X - min.X, max.Y - min.Y);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(imageCrop);
        Rectangle cropRect = new Rectangle(new Point(min.X,min.Y), new Size(max.X - min.X, max.Y - min.Y));
        g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, max.X - min.X, max.Y - min.Y), cropRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.Save();
        return imageCrop;
    }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing: `(check == Color.Black)` which means: is the reference `check` pointing to the same instance as the reference `Color.Black` --> this will never be true.

you have to compare the actual color:

```
(check.ToArgb() == Color.Black.ToArgb())
```